# postfix configuration ubuntu upgrade: what to choose?

Tags: upgrade, postfix

During dist upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04 I am asked to choose postfix configuration from:

- No configuration
- Internet Site
- Internet with smarthost
- Satellite system
- Local only

I don't remember having ever used this program (but perhaps some system processes or something I installed in the past used it?). What is the safest choice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you choose No configuration it will leave your current configuration unchanged. I would choose this option. Backup /etc/postfix folder just in case before choosing this option.